# Getting the numbers from an array of football positions using regex

Tags: java, regex

I need some help in trying to read the positions off the positions so I can use them to create panels of textfields for a football app I'm creating. Not entirely sure what to do next...

```
    String[] positions = {"4-4-2", "4-3-3", "3-5-2", "5-3-2", "3-4-3", "4-5-1"};

    JComboBox select = new JComboBox(positions);
    this.add(select, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    select.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            select.getItemAt(select.getSelectedIndex());
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d\\-\\d\\-\\d");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(select.toString());
            m.find();
            System.out.println();
        }
    });
    setVisible(true);
```

Comment: `"4-4-2".split("-")` works great. Why make it more complicated than that?

Comment: @cricket_007 Nit: [`split` uses regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-).

Comment: what do you need the output to be ? Do you need to get 4, 4, 2 ?

Comment: @svasa yes like that, so that then i can take the values and use them in fields

Comment: Why not just have them as `int[]` in the first place? `int[][] positions = {{4, 4, 2}, {4, 3, 3} etc};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want regex, you can do like this :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d)\\-(\\d)\\-(\\d)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(select.toString());
if(m.find())
{
    System.out.println( "Position 1 is : " + m.group(1) );
    System.out.println( "Position 2 is : " + m.group(2) );
    System.out.println( "Position 3 is : " + m.group(3) );
}
```

But yes, you can just use split() instead.